# SQL select all if parameter is null and order by Date else return specific item

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have the next stored procedure:

```
create procedure GetX
(
@IDX int
)
as
begin
    select * from dbo.X 
    where IDX = case when @IDX IS NULL then IDX 
    else @IDX end 
end
go
```

dbo.X is a table that has multiple columns including a primary key IDX and a ModifiedDate which is modified each time a row is modified.

The stored procedure should do the following:
- if the parameter is null then return all the rows from the table ORDERED BY the ModifiedDate in desc order
- otherwise return just the row that matches the ID

Where should I put the ORDER BY so the code could work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create procedure GetX
(
@IDX int
)
as
begin
    select * from dbo.X 
    where IDX = case when @IDX IS NULL then IDX 
    else @IDX end 
    ORDER BY ModifiedDate desc
end
go
```